# C++ lint: detect improper pass by value

Tags: c++

Howdy. Is there a lint tool which can find all function declarations accepting non-primitive arguments by value. My googleFu failed.

Thanks.

Comment: You can try splint but its just a tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net) can do this (among a wide variety of other useful checks). Since this particular situation is considered a "style" warning in Cppcheck, you will want to use the `--enable=all` command line switch.

Comment: I see it comes with CodeBlocks. Thanks for mentioning --enable=all switch.